Why is my JS not working on initial load?
I'm having weird issues with one of my JS Files that I added via a child theme. I have enqueued it in the functions.php and added some vars with wp_localize_script.
wp_enqueue_script('header-astra', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/header-astra.js');
wp_localize_script('header-astra', 'WP_FRONTPAGE', array('isfrontPage' => json_encode($isfrontPage), 'siteurl' => get_option('siteurl')));

The file loads without a problem, but the code itself is not working. It's JQuery that I've added in a jquery ready
function.
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  if (screen.width < 921) {
    $(".ast-menu-toggle").on("click", function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass("active-submenu")) {
        $(".ast-menu-toggle").removeClass("active-submenu");
      } else {
        $(".ast-menu-toggle").removeClass("active-submenu");
        $(this).addClass("active-submenu");
      }
    });
  }
..... 
)}

This code does NOT work when I first open the page after clearing the cache / opening it in incognito. When I refresh the page it works without problems.
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

This sounds like a synchronisation problem. Maybe there is another piece of jquery working on the same classes. Then it depends on which one is executed first. If both are in cache they are likely to be executed in the order they are in the code. But if they need to be loaded it might be the smallest file arriving first and then gets executed.
